# Type error when accessing API data and insert into a CSV file

Tags: python, data-retrieval

I am trying to use python to access an api, pull specified data from it and add it to a csv file, under the correct element headings. I keep getting the error:

`name = item['name'] TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'` for the line near the start of the first loop: .

I can't figure out what I've done wrong:

```
import requests
import csv

from pprint import pprint as pp

aHeader = ['name', 'birth_year', 'height', 'mass']
with open('star_wars_people2.csv', 'w') as file:
    file = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=aHeader)
    file.writeheader()


def get_info():
    for item in data:
        name = item['name']
        birth_year = item['birth_year']
        height = item['height']
        mass = item['mass']
        with open('star_wars_people2.csv', 'a') as aFile:
            aFile.write(name + birth_year + height + mass + "\n")


for i in range(5):
    user_input = input("Pick a number between 1 and 83 to find the associated Star Wars character: ")
    endpoint2 = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/{}/'.format(user_input)
    response = requests.get(endpoint2)
    data = response.json()
    pp(data)

    user_input2 = input("Would you like to add this info to a file? ")
    if user_input2 == 'y' or 'Y':
        get_info()
    else:
        print('No problem!')
```

I'm quite new to code, but I noticed that when I targeted the whole api, and used the code below, it worked to target one specific element - but I can't then translate this to specifying a page and targeting multiple elements:

```
endpoint1 = 'https://swapi.dev/api/people/'
response = requests.get(endpoint1)
data = response.json()
pp(data)

aHeader = ['name', 'birth_year', 'height', 'mass']
with open('star_wars_people2.csv', 'w') as file:
    file = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=aHeader)
    file.writeheader()


# def get_info():
for item in data['results']:
    with open('star_wars_people2.csv', 'a') as aFile:
        aFile.write(item['name'] + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you want to pass `data` as argument to the function as `def get_info(data):` and in the prompt loop you will call it as `get_info(data)`

The error you got means that `item` variable is not a dict-like object as you expect but string. `data` is already the dictionary that you want to parse so doing for loop over it you will iterate over key of this dict (in your case variable `item` will take values as "name", "birth_year", etc).

```
def get_info(data):
    with open("star_wars_people2.csv", "a") as aFile:
        aFile.write(
            data["name"] + data["birth_year"] + data["height"] + data["mass"] + "\n"
        )
```